# Python 3.x Beginner: TypeError: dog() takes no arguments

Tags: python

```
class animal(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def eat(self,food):
        print("{} is eating".format(self.name,food))


class dog():

    def fetch(self,thing):
        print("{} get the {}".format(self.name,thing))

s = dog('r')
```

> error:  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\EclipseWorkspaces\csse120\LearnPython\inheritance.py", line 14, in
>   
>           s = dog('r') TypeError: dog() takes no arguments
>
> ```
> Cant figure out whats wrong, please help.
> ```

Comment: Looks like an inheritance exercise. :-) Perhaps you forgot to inherit `class dog`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bit late posting an answer, but try adding two underscores per each side of init, 

not

```
 _init_
```

should be

```
__init__
```

```
class animal(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing that dog inherits form animal

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name


    def eat(self,food):
        print("{} is eating".format(self.name,food))


class Dog(Animal):

    def fetch(self,thing):
        print("{} get the {}".format(self.name,thing))

s = Dog('r')
```

Comment: I think `s = dog('dog')` should be in outside of the class dog block. isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

As your error indicates you are trying to create a object of Dog class by passing 'r' parameter to Dog class constructor function. But Dog class does not have a constructor function which accept a char or a string literal as a parameter. It seems like you are trying to use Animal class constructor to create Dog object (Dogs are a subclass of Animal class)

```
class animal(object):
  def __init__(self,name):
      self.name = name
```

To solve this error you should first subclass the Dog class and then create a Dog object.
To subclass Animal class,

```
class dog(animal):
  def fetch(self,thing):
      print("{} get the {}".format(self.name,thing))
```

Now you can use the Animal class constructor and create Dog objects using `s = dog('r')` statement.

Tip :- I think it is good to use CapWords convention from the beginning for class names as described in the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) styling conventions.